# extends RecyclerView.Adapter not available

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

trying extend my class with "extends RecycleView.Adapter" but it seams like it is not "available" , I Rebuilded and cleaned up the project but it's no help.
build.cradle : (in case that have anything to do with it)

```
 minSdkVersion 15
 targetSdkVersion 23
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

(thank U for any help)

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import its library as follows :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
```

Example :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Make sure that you are importing `import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;`

Your class should look like this :

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
```

Comment: Perfect!! You're the best:), -is there any simple explenation to why  I had to import that Library (shouldn't it be imported from the begining as it is a part of android) - sorry if that question sounds silly-I'm a newbie...

Comment: @PawelB You're welcome, mark my answer as acorrect if it helped (green check); Answering your question I guess it's actually implemented (I guess) I created a sample and I typed RecyclerView and it doesn't fail...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue where I could not extend **RecyclerView.Adapter** and it was that I copied and pasted the following:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

but I should have replaced the :appcompat with :recyclerview

Here is the correct lines in the dependencies section of the gradle script build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
```

Hope this helps someone wondering why they could not extend RecyclerView.Adapter